# From double to float in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

My understanding is that all numbers in JavaScript are double-precision floating-point. How can I convert a double to a float in JavaScript? I understand the precision loss, but that is tolerable.

I need to depict C style floating point numbers

Comment: One way would be to use `new Float32Array([yourNumber])[0]`, but it’s not supported in all browsers. Why do you need the lost precision?

Comment: What do you need a "float" for? Context will help us understand what you are going for

Comment: I need to depict c style floating point numbers

Comment: For what? JS doesn't have C-style `float`s. Are you interfacing with C code?

Comment: What function/library are you trying to call, and using what means? REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work in modern engines:

```
function doubleToFloat ( d ) {
    if ( Float32Array )
        return new Float32Array([d])[0];
}
```

Note that the data type of the result is still number (double precision), but it only uses 32 bits of information. I added a fallback for the case that Float32Array is not available:

```
function doubleToFloat ( d ) {
    if ( Float32Array )
        return new Float32Array( [ d ] )[ 0 ];

    if ( d === 0 )
        return d;

    var sign = 2*(d >= 0) - 1;
    var b = Math.abs( d ).toString( 2 );
    var decimalIndex = b.indexOf( '.' );
    var oneIndex = b.indexOf( '1' );
    var exponent, mantissa, round, result;

    if( decimalIndex === -1 ) {
        exponent = b.length - 1;
        mantissa = b.substr( 1, 23 );
        round = +( mantissa.length === 23 && b[24] === '1' );
        result = sign*( parseInt( '1' + mantissa, 2 ) + round )*Math.pow( 2, exponent - mantissa.length );
    } else if ( decimalIndex === 1 ) {
        exponent = 1 - oneIndex;       
        if ( oneIndex === 0 ) {
            mantissa = '1' + b.substr( 2, 23 );
            round = +( mantissa.length === 24 && b[25] === '1' );
            result = sign*( parseInt( mantissa, 2 ) + round )*Math.pow( 2, 1 - mantissa.length );
        } else {
            mantissa = b.substr( oneIndex, 24 );
            round = +( mantissa.length === 24 && b[oneIndex + 24] === '1' );
            result = sign*( parseInt( mantissa, 2 ) + round )*Math.pow( 2, 1 + exponent - mantissa.length );
        }
    } else {
        exponent = decimalIndex - 1;
        mantissa = b.replace( '.', '' ).substr( 1, 23 );
        round = +( mantissa.length === 23 && b.replace( '.', '' )[24] === '1' );
        result = sign*( parseInt( '1' + mantissa, 2 ) + round )*Math.pow( 2, decimalIndex - mantissa.length - 1 );
    }

    if ( exponent < -126 )
        return 0;
    if ( exponent > 127 )
        return sign*Infinity;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this gives pretty bad precision

Comment: @asehgal Yeah, isn’t that exactly what you wanted?

Comment: I didnt want BAD precision. I said a 32 bit representation is desired even if it comes with precision loss.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is:

```
var doubleValue = Math.random()
var floatValue = ((doubleValue * 1e7) | 0) / 1e7
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Math.fround()` - it returns the nearest 32-bit single precision float representation of a number.

[Math.fround() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/fround)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).